# mod_wsgi (pid=*): Target WSGI script '/root/project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python

Tags: python-3.x, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

getting this error when making website live. When

```
    path set in wsgi
        WSGIDaemonProcess demo python-path=/root/election python-home=/root/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup demo
        WSGIScriptAlias / /root/election/election/wsgi.py
```

this is error from my logs

```
    mod_wsgi (pid=*): Target WSGI script '/root/election/election/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python m$[time] [wsgi:error] [pid 17712:tid 140454280738560] [remote 43.241.144.192:527] mod_wsgi (pid=*): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/root/election/election/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/election/election/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I verified that path is correctly specified that is as below
path to wsgi

```
/root/election/election/wsgi.py
```

virtual env path

```
/root/venv
```

tried reinstalling wsgi by below command. but still error not solved

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

I even given persmission of 777 to my project directory and virtualevn still geting this error

output of these command ask other peoples so. It is as below.

```
>>> django.__file__
'/root/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/root/venv'
```

followed [this](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/378) and googled other answers but although this question asked many time and duplicated but still it is is not answerd.

Comment: is there django installed in your venv as from your error that should not be case ->
ImportError: No module named 'django'

Comment: yes django is installed in venv

Comment: 2 questions: did you follow the mod_wsgi instruction? Why dont you use pip install and did you install the ...dev Version of Apache?